# How do I apply multiple transparent leaf branch images to main branch model more naturally?

Tags: modeling, transparency, image, duplicate

The branch model has transparent images of a 3D leafy branch that I modeled after a white pine tree branch which I rendered into an image then duplicated, and it feels to, organized that and all the images feel the same and I don't want them looking too flat when people see them at a certain angle. I tried following the examples of video games as well as IanHubert of how they would model trees in a lazy but vary detailed way. However, I just can't seem to get it right I looked for references online, but it didn't do much is there a way to make the branches look more natural?[image]

Comment: do you want an animation or just a still image? for a still image you could simple use the track to constraint for your images and track them to your camera

Comment: Maybe you should work on the main branch itself, like twist it a bit and give it a bit of pines too?

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DMEyev4y" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DMEyev4y/) Forgot to add this so you all could see it.